# Can the uploadcare widget be used without the uploadcare service?

Tags: file-upload, uploadcare

Can [uploadcare-widget](https://github.com/uploadcare/uploadcare-widget) be used without using the upload care service?

The goal:

- Use the widget (specifically to allow users to upload files from their google drive/dropbox accounts).
- Instead of using upload care's backend, use your own backend, i.e. node.js/aws s3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it can. It's open source!

Although you will have to either replicate or get rid of functionality that relies on [Uploadcare](https://uploadcare.com) infrastructure:

- uploads (this is the easiest part)
- fetching files from social networks and cloud storage services
- image preview and cropping that relies on Uploadcare CDN

So unless you're moving enormous amounts of files, most cost efficient way is to use Uploadcare as it is. BTW, you can use your own S3 storage and even upload directly to your S3 buckets.

Comment: Thanks @mojo. Point 2 "fetching files from social networks and cloud storage services" is what most interests me. Is this capability handled by the uploadcare backend? I assumed there was no server involved and it was limited to communication between the user's browser and the cloud service (i.e. dropbox).

Comment: that part is serverside.